# NestJS - Purpose of mixins and how are they different from inheritance?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, nestjs, mixins

Nestjs docs have no mention of `mixin`, so this is what I gathered from google and stackoverflow:

- A mixin is a way to share code between classes in nest.
- It is a class that contains methods that can be used by other classes, and can be registered as a provider using the `@Injectable()` decorator.
- Mixins are used to add additional functionality to a class without modifying the original class, and can be used with controllers, services, pipes, and guards.
- Examples often include classes inheriting from mixins: `class SomeClass extends MixinClass {}`

At first I thought that this is for semantics sake, as inheritance implies a certain relationship between two classes, while a mixin is a way of sharing code. But the mechanics of using a mixin in nest are still relying on inheritance(`extends` keyword).

What I am missing about mixins? How are they different from inheritance?
It seems that `class SomeClass extends SomeOtherClassThatIsntAMixin {}` achieves the same results.

Comment: The OP is correct with the observation, and the questions ask already show a better understanding of what a mixin should be and ever was meant to be in comparison to calling the pattern of... _"a class-creating factory-function where the created class then gets extended"_ ...a mixin. And yes, every augmented/aggregated behavior of such a type is acquired by inheritance (introducing an _"is a"_  relationship) and not by mixin based composition (which would result in a  _"has a"_  relationship). The OP has to live with this reality and not fight the wording but does not need to doubt her/himself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One big thing you're missing about mixins is that they are *functions* that return a class reference that Nest can then instantiate. It would be like letting a class have a `protected name: string` property that child classes could override, but instead of having to create a child class that extends the parent class, you can just use `MixinClass('someNewName')` and the function *should* return a child class reference with the new `name` property. The `AuthGuard` and `FileInterceptor` are two mixins that pass options to the new class without you having to create these new child classes.

Edit:

Something else I forgot to initially mention is that mixins allow you to hide the constructor of the class reference. This is useful if you have something that you always want injected, but want to allow user customization to come in with. In the `AuthGuard`, we optionally inject the passport options set by the `PassportModule.register()` method, and the strategy passed via `AuthGuard('strategy')` does not interfere with those options. By using a closure we can avoid letting devs accidentally overwrite the constructor which could cause the class to fail, or cause Typescript to complain leading to a headache for the dev to deal with

Comment: And yet the pattern of a factory-function which creates an ad-hoc implementation of an anonymous extended class is not a mixin. It is what it is - a class-creating factory-function. And since it always goes together with extending from such a created class, it is based from its creation to its usage on pure inheritance which might be better named _"dynamic sub-classing"_ or _"dynamic sub-typing"_.

Comment: To an extent, I think it depends. Most Mixins in Nest have the express purpose of being used directly **or** extended (like the `AuthGuard`). For the factory-function (so long as you mean `useFactory`) you're usually not going to extend what the factory returns. Also, the factory returns an _instance_ of the class while a mixin returns a _reference_ to a class that still has to have `new` called on it.